# Deploying via Google Cloud build trigger "sh: 1: jest: Permission denied"

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, jestjs

I'am deploying a nodejs application in the google cloud platform.

My cloudbuild.yaml looks like this :

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm"
    args: ["install"]

  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm"
    args: ["run", "test"]

  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args: ["app", "deploy"]
```

I set up all the APIs and enabled them (App engine etc..) and deployed via the command :

```
gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .
```

The deployment is successful and are the steps are passed (the test via Jest).

But when the deployment is triggered via a **Bitbucket** repository, I get this error in the step 1 (testing step) :

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm

> server@1.0.0 test /workspace
> jest --detectOpenHandles

sh: 1: jest: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! server@1.0.0 test: `jest --detectOpenHandles`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2020-03-13T13_42_08_361Z-debug.log
```

So the deployment is succeful via gcloud SDK , but returns errors via a trigger.

Any help please

**EDIT**
I created a Github repo and repeated the same steps , the same error in the trigger :

Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm

```
> server@1.0.0 test /workspace
> jest --detectOpenHandles

sh: 1: jest: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! server@1.0.0 test: `jest --detectOpenHandles`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2020-03-13T14_09_58_093Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 4):

**Fixed**:

I changed my test script in package.json from:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch"
  },
```

to:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "sh node_modules/.bin/jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch"
  },
```

Comment: Any explication why is that ?

Comment: When you trigger a build from a repository, Build triggers use a shallow clone of your repository. This means that the single commit that triggered the automatic build is checked out in the workspace volume.

Your repository directories are attached to the workspace volume. That is why you should include the whole path on the package.json.

You could prevent altering your script, by adding the dir field on your build steps like this:

dir:'sh node_modules/.bin'