# CI with google cloud build and unit testing Jest in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build

I'm setting up a CI/CD pipeline using Google cloud build, I'm doing 3 simple steps : install, test and deploy, here is my CloudBuild.yaml file :

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm"
    args: ["install"]

  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm"
    args: ["run", "test"]

  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args: ["app", "deploy"]
```

And here is my package.json where I need to specify the hole path of the jest so it can identify it, otherwise I set it : **"test": "jest"** the step 2 of the build will fail and it will not recognize it.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "sh node_modules/.bin/jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch"
  },
```

In this case I need to always push the node_modules to the github repo to find the module jest, but it's not a good practise.

Any ideas how can I fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Why jest isn't in your dependencies? Maybe it is only in the test dependencies only and you first step doesn't install this dependency?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying via Google Cloud build trigger "sh: 1: jest: Permission denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60671752/deploying-via-google-cloud-build-trigger-sh-1-jest-permission-denied)